# Simplify Rails Method and nested variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I have 2 methods as seen below:

```
def post(type, params=nil)
    if params
    @animalCategory.post(type, params:params[:params], header:{...}) 
    else 
      @animalCategory.post(type, header:{...}) 
    end
  end

  def put(route, params=nil)
    if params
      @animalCategory.put(type, params:params[:params], header:{...})  
    else
      @animalCategory.put(type, header:{...})  
    end
  end
```

It gets called like this:

```
 animal_category.put '/cat', params: data
```

I have a wrapper for two functions above. They basically do the same thing except one calls a post and the other calls a put. I'm wondering if there's a way to merge/simplify it. Also, is there a suggested way to simplify the extraction of params:params[:params]?

Comment: define a function that revieve an action in addition to other parameters.  inside the function by simple if either do post or put. please let me know about your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def put_or_post(http_method, type, params=nil)
  if params
    @animalCategory.send(http_method, type, params:params[:params], header:{...}) 
  else 
    @animalCategory.send(http_method, type, header:{...}) 
  end
end
```

Use [Object#send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) to call methods from variables

You can then refactor the other methods to call this one:

```
def put(*args)
  put_or_post :put, *args
end

def post(*args)
  put_or_post :post, *args
end
```

and leave your original call signature (`animal_category.put`) the same

Comment: I think object.send is what I'm looking for. Does that mean I can leave the call for it as is?
eg.  animal_category.put '/cat', params: data can stay the same?

Comment: And by the way, you didn't define `params` as a keyword param, so `params: data` wouldn't work, you just need to pass `data` as the second argument, remove the `params: `